# Delphi XE5 Android deploy, not showing embedded forms

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am using Firemonkey in Delphi XE5 to develop an Android app. When i deploy the APP and install .apk in    a Sony Xperia ZL, the application forms doesnt load correct, to specify this im using a MainForm that contains simple TPanel. When the app start, another form is created and is embedded in Tpanel of the MainForm. To do this, im using this procedure:

```
procedure EmbeddedForm(Aparent:Tcontrol; AForm:TCustomForm);
 begin
  while Aform.ChildrenCount>0 do
  begin
   Aform.Children[0].Parent:=Aparent;
  end;
 end;
```

If i run the application in AVD, the forms load correct, and show all the forms. But when i install the .apk in my phone, the application start and load the MainForm but with a TButton in the middle of the Panel, when i touch it, the next form is created and Show but over the MainForm. If i touch backbutton, im back to the MainForm with the button in the Panel.

I dont have any button in this form, can Firemonkey create this when the app is deployed? Did Firemonkey understand what im trying to do with this forms?

I dont know, if i can build apps in Firemonkey in this way. Working in one MainForm, then loading all other forms inside this. I used to work like this in windows apps and never got a problem.

Comment: Your approach of "docking" form with changing every control parent is really bad. I cannot test your FM code right now to give you solution, but instead of moving controls try docking whole form with `AForm.Parent := AParent;` or instead of using forms try frames.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thank you. I've tried frames, and now it works!